# How i want to write function when i click on button calculate order, it will show the ouput

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

The cleaning total I got is from total laundry.

I have written the function for calculate tax amount and total order amount. but I'm not sure which line got error. It's more confusing when I only can use one button (calculate order) for 2 function.

```js
function calculateTaxAmount() {
  let cleaningTotal = document.getElementById("cleaningTotal");
  let tax = 5.75;
  let taxAmount = cleaningTotal * tax / 100;
  document.getElementById("taxAmount").value = taxAmount;
}

function processOrder() {
  var f1 = document.getElementById('sum').value;
  var f2 = document.getElementById('sumpants').value;
  var f3 = document.getElementById('sumItem1').value;
  var f4 = document.getElementById('sumItem2').value;
  var f5 = document.getElementById('sumItem3').value;
  var f6 = document.getElementById('sumItem4').value;

  if (f1 == "") f1 = 0;
  if (f2 == "") f2 = 0;
  if (f3 == "") f3 = 0;
  if (f4 == "") f4 = 0;
  if (f5 == "") f5 = 0;
  if (f6 == "") f6 = 0;

  var result = parseInt(f1) + parseInt(f2) + parseInt(f3) + parseInt(f4) + parseInt(f5) + parseInt(f6);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('cleaningTotal').value = result;
  }
  var orderTotal = cleaningTotal + tax; {
    document.getElementById('orderTotal').value = result
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Calculate Order" onclick="processOrder()"><br><br>
<label>Cleaning Total</label>
</td>
<td>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="cleaningTotal" id="cleaningTotal" value="">
  </div>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tbl-foot">
  <td colspan="3">
    <label>Tax Rate</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="taxRate" id="taxRate" value="5.75">%
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tbl-foot">
  <td colspan="3">
    <label>Tax Amount : </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="taxAmount" id="taxAmount" onclick="processOrder()" value="">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tbl-foot">
  <td colspan="3">
    <label>Order Total : </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="orderTotal" id="orderTotal" value="">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. I had to change `cleaning total` to `cleaningTotal` - please check the console errors - you are accessing html fields that are not in your code. Please change to make a [mcve]

Comment: Please add the rest of the HTML if you want any help. I suggest you use delegation and addEventListener("input" to make the form update automatically without having to push buttons